# Broblem in ACTION_CALL code in android studio m

Tags: android-studio

**my program stopped when i click on callbutton what is the problem**

```
public void callbutton(View v) {  try{
             intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:111*"+phone+"#"));
            startActivity(intent);
            }catch (ActivityNotFoundException e){
                Toast.makeText(data.this, "noooo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }}
```

**i Wrote the permission in manifests   **

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**On API 23 or higher:** you most use this code:

```
public void calling(String phoneNumber) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(phoneNumber));
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

OR::

```
public void callind(String phone) {
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL); //use ACTION_CALL class
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(phone));    //this is the phone number calling
    //check permission
    //If the device is running Android 6.0 (API level 23) and the app's targetSdkVersion is 23 or higher,
    //the system asks the user to grant approval.
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        //request permission from user if the app hasn't got the required permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},   //request specific permission from user
                10);
        return;
    }else {     //have got permission
        try{
            startActivity(callIntent);  //call activity and make phone call
        }
        catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "did not work", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

**On API 23 and less:** you can use this code:

```
public void callind(String phoneNumber) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(phoneNumber));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**in tow ways you have to  add manifests permission:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: i found the answer for my question thank you every one.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

```
public void callbutton(View v) {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:1234567890"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }catch (ActivityNotFoundException e){
        Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "noooo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```